# Play a video with ffmpeg and SDL2 on a Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: python, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, sdl-2, ffmpeg-python

I want to create a python script that decodes a h264 1080p video and outputs it via SDL2 on a Raspberry Pi 5. The Raspberry Pi 5 is able to play a h264 1080p video without problem using VLC. Total CPU load with VLC is about 10%. However decoding with ffmpeg and outputting via SDL2 uses around 70% CPU load. Since I want to be able to switch seamlessly between two output videos I will need to decode two videos at the same time. Therefore 70% CPU load for one transcoded 1080p video is not acceptable. How can I make the code more efficient and why is VLC so much more efficient?

This is my current python script:

```py
import numpy as np
import ffmpeg  # ffmpeg-python
import sdl2.ext

in_file = ffmpeg.input('bbb1080_x264.mp4', re=None)

width = 1920
height = 1080

process1 = (
    in_file
    .output('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='bgra')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)

sdl2.ext.init()
window = sdl2.ext.Window("Hello World!", size=(width, height))
window.show()
windowsurface = sdl2.SDL_GetWindowSurface(window.window)
windowArray = sdl2.ext.pixels3d(windowsurface.contents)

sdl2.ext.mouse.hide_cursor()

while True:
    in_bytes = process1.stdout.read(width * height * 4)

    if not in_bytes:
        break

    in_frame = (
        np
        .frombuffer(in_bytes, np.uint8)
        .reshape([height, width, 4])
        .transpose(1, 0, 2)
    )

    for event in sdl2.ext.get_events():
        if event.type == sdl2.SDL_QUIT:
            exit()

    windowArray[:] = in_frame
    window.refresh()

process1.wait()
```

Also it is interesting to note that when I start VLC on a Raspberry Pi 5 this is the output on the terminal

```
[00007fff78c1a550] avcodec decoder error: cannot start codec (h264_v4l2m2m)
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
[00007fff68002d70] gles2 generic error: parent window not available
[00007fff68002d70] xcb generic error: window not available
[00007fff680013f0] mmal_xsplitter vout display: Try drm
[00007fff68002d70] drm_vout generic: <<< OpenDrmVout: Fmt=I420
[00007fff68002d70] drm_vout generic error: Failed to get xlease`
```

It indicates that VLC is not using the h264_v4l2m2m hardware acceleration.

Comment: First off why are you using python

Comment: because development is easier and ffmpeg-python is just a wrapper for the ffmpeg binary so decoding should not be slower than using it in any other language.

Comment: VLC is written in C and C++. In this case you are using python to display SDL2 frames which is processor intensive and shouldn't be done in Python. Can you use ffmpeg directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to reduce the processor load:

1. Enable hw acceleration for decoding
2. Disable format conversion
3. Avoiding the stdout

Code with the changes:

```
in_file = ffmpeg.input('bbb1080_hevc.mp4', hwaccel='auto')

width = 1920
height = 1080

process1 = (
    in_file
    .output('/dev/null', format='rawvideo')
    .run_async(pipe_stdout=True)
)
```

This is now pure decoding in hardware and actually almost diminishes the ffmpeg processor load. However this code is now of course unusable. I would need to deal with the format conversion in python and find out why the stdout is so slow. I switched to C instead as I should have done from the beginning and @qwr suggested in his comment already.

**Edit:**
I got it working now using C and following this tutorial closely:
http://www.dranger.com/ffmpeg/

Then I call the video player I created in C via ctypes in python. This way everything is much more intuitive than calling PySDL2 and piping the ffmpeg input.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. You can also ask on video.stackexchange.com and see what they say there

Comment: @qwr My goal was to use pure python to call ffmpeg and sdl2 and create a video player that can switch seamlessly between two videos. The problem was that decoding wasn't nearly as fast as calling ffmpeg directly and vlc was even faster than ffmpeg and I could not figure out why because under the hood python-ffmpeg just calls the ffmpeg binary. The solution was that the format conversion was what was making my ffmpeg call so slow. Moreover outputting it to stdout was somehow much slower in python-ffmpeg than in a commandline ffmpeg call. When enabling hwaccel i got to pretty decent speeds.

Comment: I now switched to C and got it working following this tutorial: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpegtutorial_all.html and it was much more intuitive than calling sdl2 via pysdl2.